# Polygon function creates strange shape

Tags: r, plot, polygon

I'm trying to plot multiple distributions on the same plot. For some reason when I use the polygon function, it doesn't sit on the x-axis, and starts to levitate.

Grateful for any advice on how to stop this!

```
x <- seq(0,5,length=1000) 
plot(x = x,                   
     y = dnorm(x, 1.5, 0.4),                  
     type = "l",     
     col = "white",
     axes = FALSE,
     mgp = c(2, 2, 2), 
     ylim=c(0,2),                         # Set limit of y-axis
     frame.plot=TRUE, 
     xlab = "theta",                         
     ylab = "plausibility",
     font.main = 1,
     main=paste("Distributions"),
     lwd=2
)      
polygon(x,dnorm(x, 1.5, 0.4),col=1,border = NULL) 
polygon(x,dnorm(x, 1, 0.5),col=2,border = NULL)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation of `?polygon` states

> `x, y vectors containing the coordinates of the vertices of the polygon.`

We have to add `0` as a vertex to both the `x` and the `y` coordinates.

```
polygon(x=c(0, x), y=c(0, dnorm(x, 1.5, 0.4)), col=1, border=NULL) 
polygon(x=c(0, x), y=c(0, dnorm(x, 1, 0.5)), col=2, border=NULL)
```

***Result***

[image]